# Suggestion on JSF authorization

Tags: jsf, role-base-authorization

I learnt how to use container authentication with JDBC realm.
I searched a lot on internet but I couldn't find anything on JSF authorization except the following article.
[JSF authorization](http://java.sys-con.com/node/250254)

My goal is to avoid access to protected pages using direct links and to show/hide menu items  and form components based on the authenticated user privileges.
The last part can be implemented using the rendered attribute of JSF tags  but before creating my own dirty and high coupled solution I wonder if there are some specific best practices or libraries that can help. in fact the number of components to be conditionally rendered is quite high and I wouldn't like to write a specific function for each of them.
Perhaps I can create for each authenticated user a map with the names (id) of all the conditionally rendered components and a single function with a String parameter (the unique name/id of the component). Is that a good idea ? What alternatives do I have ?
I wouldn't like to add to the project other general purpose frameworks such as spring for using only a small part of them (the security one).

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Expression Language version in Java EE 6 you should be able to use expressions like these:

```
<h:inputText rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.isUserInRole('foo')}" />
```

With older versions, you can create a managed bean of this form:

```
public class RoleMap implements Map<String, Boolean> {

    public Boolean get(Object key) {
        ExternalContext extCtxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                              .getExternalContext();
        return extCtxt.isUserInRole(key.toString());
    }

    //TODO: other methods; mostly throwing UnsupportedOperationException
```

The test can then be expression in the form:

```
<h:inputText rendered="#{roleMap['foo']}" />
```

Third party frameworks offer other options, such as the Apache Tomahawk library's `visibleOnUserRole` component attributes.

Comment: `#{facesContext.externalContext.isUserInRole('foo')}` can be shortened to `#{request.isUserInRole('foo')}` if you don't care about the servlet/portlet environment abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/), a dedicated security framework (and supposedly erasier to use than Spring Security).